# Java Program running through zookeeper

Tags: java, hadoop, client-server, client, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to run the maven built java program through zookeeper , So that if one machine fails the program runs automatically from other machine?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "build java program through zookeeper". Zookeeper is a service for distributed synchronization. You can use ZK API in your application and make it work for leader election in case of the process failure, here's an example of how this can be done: [ZK Guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection)

But keep in mind that you need at least 3 ZK processes running on a separate machines to form a cluster. You can run your application on the same machines